# Cast a base class issues

Tags: c++

```
class YourInterface {
public:
    YourInterface(){
    }

    virtual ~YourInterface(){
    }

    virtual void saveData(Data data) = 0; //Pure virtual = Childs are forced to implement those functions to become non abstract
    virtual Data loadData() = 0;
};

//One implementation to load and save data to/from a xml file
class XmlImplementation : public YourInterface {
public:
    XmlImplementation(){
    }

    virtual ~XmlImplementation(){
    }

    //Overriding functions:
    void saveData(Data data){
        //Save data to a xml file here
    }

    Data loadData(){
        //Load data from a xml file here
    }
};

void main(){
    YourInterface* p;
    p = (YourInterface*) new XmlImplementation();

    p->loadData(); //We just want to get our Data here, we dont care whether its from a xml or binary file etc.
}
```

Please take that as an example, I know it is not good but I can't write any better than that.

I'd like to know better why the cast in main refuses to work properly ? and it has been suggested as an errorful cast.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: on my compiler it seems to work better without error. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "refuses to work properly?"

Comment: What you use is the most powerful function provided in C++: run-time polymorphism via virtual functions. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I realize my misunderstanding now, I have learned this polymorphism with virtual functions long ago, I know them too but am sure not as much as you do. :).

Comment: As long as  you have `void main` the program is invalid as (hosted) C++ and can do anything if it compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with the code, except that the cast is actually unnecessary. The code would compile and work fine without it.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, very insightful.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the (C-style or otherwise) cast here. Your `main()` function (which should always return `int`) should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    YourInterface* p = new XmlImplementation();

    p->loadData();
}
```

If you're getting an error, it's not because of the cast.

**N.B**: In C++, it's customary to use [`static_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) when typecasting from a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to a base class.

Comment: No, `static_cast` is the one to use when casting to a base class, because it's always safe and well-defined. `dynamic_cast` is used to go the other way.

Comment: @Mark: D'oh! I really should go back to sleep. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you :-), I was having my breakfast and there were some visitors behind me watching I couldn't post any thing at all. I finish my toothbrushing now, so many people from Australia by the way :D. Seriously It's very kind and good of you, THanks.

Comment: @Mark, `static_cast` can be used to go to a derived class, particularly when RTTI is not available for some reason. No cast is necessary when going to a base class.